# Running ssh client in minishift

Tags: ssh, openshift, minishift

I am attempting to download some html files to a **minishift** pod running **Apache** so the web site is updated every 10 minutes. I intend to use a shell script to copy the files using **ssh**. If I try to use the **ssh** command I receive the error that the **uid** does not exist

```
sh-4.4$ ssh 192.168.10.20
No user exists for uid 1000160000
```

What do I need to do to enable **ssh** to work?
Once I have it up and running on **minishift** I will then move it to our **OpenShift** server.